# how to display all folders,subfolders and file in ckfinder

Tags: php, ckfinder

I was installed `ckfinder` in my script and integrated it with `ckeditor`,
 my ckfinder path is `public_html/assest/libs/ckfinder`
but when click on the `browse` button from `ckeditor` it show 3 folders automatically 
files,images,flash. 
I want to display all folders and sub folders  and files in these folders.
**my settings is:**

```
 $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => '*',
        'folder' => '',
        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => true,
        'folderRename' => true,
        'folderDelete' => true,
        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'fileRename' => true,
        'fileDelete' => true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself ,just change the first array of `ResourceType` by change `url` and `directory` values  like this

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Files',          
        'url' => $baseUrl ,//chage url to baseurl variable
        'directory' => $baseDir,//change directory to to baseDir variable 
        'maxSize' => 0,
        'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

note:`baseUrl` variable must be null so if your `baseDir` in your code set value like this
`$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);` you must comment it `//$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);`